# Encrypted mail is rejected by mailserver

Tags: email, encryption, spam-prevention

I started sending mail encrypted with openPGP (Thunderbird + Enigmail) this month and it has worked perfectly for several weeks. Today I attempted to send an encrypted message, but received this rejection from "Mail Delivery System" instead:

[Return Code 553] sid: PVV41n00f1kmamQ01 :: 5.3.0 nlpi180 DNSBL:RBL 521< 173.201.193.233 >_is_blocked.__For_information_see_http://att.net/blocks

The 173.201.193.233 is a GoDaddy IP, and DNSBL:RBL 521 means that the message was identified as spam (by who I do not know). I am using GoDaddy as the registrar for the domain name that I send the email from.

Since this first rejection, all attempts to send encrypted email have been rejected with a similar rejection message from "Mail Delivery System", but unencrypted messages go through fine.

Does this mean GoDaddy/AT&T/someone else is monitoring my emails, or did I cause this by activating an adaptive spam filter somewhere? I can see how encrypted emails would look like spam (or garbage, rather) to an unknowing spam filter. If it is my fault in unknowingly activating a spam filter, is there a good way to allow encrypted emails without completely disabling the spam filter?

Comment: Are you talking about first message to given user?  IMHO if previous messages from you and your server had been accepted by specific recipient as ham then it is a buggy filter or a malicious intention.

Comment: No, I was emailing my dad. We have already exchanged several encrypted messages before.

Comment: If your mail is being rejected by AT&T then you will have to find out the reason from AT&T which will be difficult.  Verify if the email is blocked by other email providers also.

Comment: IMHO it is better you ask the recipient to complain about rejected mail he WANTED to receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think this is GoDaddy spam policy implemented. There are quite a few people with same problem:

> In 2003, the Can't Spam Act was implemented.  Since then, large email
>   hosting companies like GoDaddy have had to constantly balance the
>   filters on their servers.  If a certain email account gets flagged as
>   spam, sometimes the entire server gets shut down until GoDaddy can
>   either adjust the filters or weed out the problem customer who is
>   spamming.  This causes a lot of other emailers whose emails go through
>   that same server to have an interruption in their service.  Therefore,
>   Godaddy (and other email hosting companies) are constantly walking a
>   fine line.  If they make the email filters too strict, the server
>   overreacts and treats our harmless emails as spam or a virus.  If they
>   make the filters too loose, then the whole server may be shut down
>   because of a spammer. When I asked why it goes through if I try to
>   resend the email, he said it's because different servers have
>   different filters and he reminded me that it is a constant balance
>   they will always be working on.... 
> (check below links for more)

here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/136986d0-4ff3-44aa-a545-af3a775386fe/outlook-error-552-message-rejected-for-spam-or-virus-content-no-virus-with-and-without?forum=outlook

and
here:
https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/go-daddy-hosting-email-error-issue.2371308/

some people changed Godaddy to another hoster to fix this problem.